# file not found exception facebook graph

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api

the code is:

```
URL img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

when excecuted, it gives me the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://graph.facebook.com/**id**/picture?type=small
```

but when i try opening the URL in the browser, it shows up just fine, so i'm guessing there's an error in that slice of code, but i have no idea about it

logcat: http://pastebin.com/Q3D3cGex

Comment: What do you set id to? '\*\*id\*\*' ??

Comment: jsonUser = facebook.request("me");
obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
String id = obj.optString("id");

Comment: Have you debugged each stage of that code?

Comment: logcat: http://pastebin.com/Q3D3cGex no, actually i didn't

Comment: well i did now, but i haven't found anything..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with authentication, I am assuming when you copy / paste the URL in the browser it uses your personal/authorized account, but accessing from java probably gets a 401.

Just open a browser in incognito mode and paste the URL and that will tell you if its an authorization issue or not.